# PhpStorm autocomplete __construct method

Tags: phpstorm

When you write `public function __` PhpStorm prompt's a list of [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

So if you, for instance, want to create a constructor for your class, you would use `__construct` magic method. For example, I typed `__con` and PhpStorm detect's my intention of creating a constructor thus a prompt window suggests me to auto-create one.

[image]

Once you hit `Enter` the method is created.

[image]

While this is pretty nice, I would really love to have the cursor automatically placed between parenthesis like this: `public function __construct(|)` *(the vertical bar "|" illustrates the cursor)*, and that would give me the ability to write the params needed for the constructor, in case I don't need any properties, I could press `Tab` and the cursor would move to the body of the method like this:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    |
}
```

From what I read in PhpStorm documentation, I did not found anywhere to be mentioned that you can edit those suggestions by PhpStorm, so I believe that in order to archive what I'm describing I have to go with a live template like this:

[image]

So my question is: Is my approach the only way to archive that or there is a way to edit the PhpStorm build-in suggestion for the class constructor magic method?

Thanks!

Comment: Live Template is very good approach to have custom code snippet into your file fast .. especially with such desired behavior. For constructor in general -- have a look at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates --> Code | PHP Constructor`. But I think this one is only used when you use `Code | Generate/Implement/Override`. BTW -- why not use that `Code | Override Methods...` or `Code | Implement Methods...` or `Code | Generate...` for such stuff?

Comment: Nice hint on `Code | Generate/Implement/Override`! I use those as well, it's just that sometimes, I don't want to use a constructor "generator" in order for it to generate a constructor that would prompt me a list of class properties to select and add them into constructor params and set them in the constructor body, sometimes you just want a plain constructor quick and easy without any prompts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, please vote for [WI-33646](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33646).